# Cant pass value as variable in this php script

Tags: php

Like the question says, I can't seem to pass a value in a variable in the following script.  If I echo the variable, it exists as expected.  If i copy and paste the echoed value into the code where $my_var is, it works.  But it wont work with $my_var ?!?!?

Context- code requires another file to create a pdf, attaches it to an email and sends it, and then displays it in the browser.  Have removed most of the code for brevity

```
$my_var = $_POST['quote_number'];
$filename = 'Quote_no' . $my_var . '.pdf';
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/quotes/' . $filename ;
require('instant_quote.php');
function send_quote($my_var) {
     //my_function code
   };
send_quote($my_var);
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
@readfile($file);
```

Comment: Tried taking that out, still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

The syntax highlighting in your example was helpful, you have incorrect matching quotes:

```
$filename = "Quote_no' . $my_var . '.pdf";
```

... should be:

```
$filename = 'Quote_no' . $my_var . '.pdf';
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake when I retyped the code, it's not in my actual code- edited to show

Comment: @Imaginate I can't see any difference in your question code, but have you tried `var_dump($_POST)` to make sure your value is actually there and doesn't contain anything you don't expect (e.g. whitespace on either end)?

Comment: Contents of var dump - `array(11) { ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["company_name"]=> string(0) "" ["design_level"]=> string(5) "basic" ["address"]=> string(0) "" ["email"]=> string(0) "" ["content"]=> string(4) "none" ["type"]=> string(7) "Landing" ["size"]=> string(11) "single page" ["product_qty"]=> string(4) "< 30" ["action"]=> string(13) "instant_quote" ["quote_number"]=> string(5) "W1741" } `

Comment: Looks fine, go through and `var_dump` every variable or function call in your script until you find something you weren't expecting

Comment: The problem seems to be with POST return, when I do this `$quote_number = 'W1741';`, it works

Comment: var_dump($_POST['quote_number']):

Comment: `string(5) "W1748" `  I'm at a loss!

Comment: Use $_POST['quote_number'] instead of $my_var then :p

Comment: Does myvar get overwritten in the file you are including?

Comment: Don't think so, if I var dump $my_var after require it's still the same value

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why this worked, but it did...

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $file . '"');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
@readfile($filename);
```

Just removed the transfer encoding and accept-ranges from the headers, and it started accepting my variable as a value... go figure

Comment: interesting... there must be some conflict between posted data and those headers being sent... +1 for working it out yourself